# Sencha Touch: How to set a limit for data in a JsonStore

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch

I'm trying to read data from Json-File and output its data in a Ext.List. But i don't want all the record to be displayed in the list. I just want the first 3 records to be displayed.
I tried already the start and limit option but it still doesn't work.

here is a part of my code

Model:

```
Ext.regModel('News', {
  fields: [
           'title', 
           'description',
           'guid' 
       ]
});
```

View:

```
new Ext.List({
    "id" : "newsOverview",
    "store" : app.stores.newsStore,
    "itemTpl" : "{title}",
    "listeners" :  {
      "itemtap" : function(list, index) {
        Ext.dispatch({
          "controller": 'news',
          "action"    : "showDetails",
          "model" : Ext.ModelMgr.create(list.getStore().getAt(index).data, 'News')         
        });         
      }
    }
})
```

Store:

```
app.stores.newsStore = new Ext.data.Store({
  "model" : "News",
  "pageSize" : 2,
  "proxy" : {
    "type" : "ajax",
    "url" : 'includes/json/news.json',
    "reader" : "json",
    "operation" : {
      "start" : 0,
      "limit" : 2
    }
  }     
});
```

json:

```
[ 
  {
    "title" : "news1",
    "description" : "description for news 1",
    "date" : "Mon Dec 19 2011 16:23:28 GMT+0100",
    "guid" : "11/22/33"
  },
  {
    "title" : "news2",
    "description" : "description for news 2",
    "date" : "Sun Dec 18 2011 12:23:28 GMT+0100",
    "guid" : "22/33/44"
  },
  {
    "title" : "news3",
    "description" : "description for news 3",
    "date" : "Sat Dec 17 2011 10:22:28 GMT+0100",
    "guid" : "33/33/44"
  },
  {
    "title" : "news4",
    "description" : "description for news 4",
    "date" : "Sat Dec 17 2011 10:21:28 GMT+0100",
    "guid" : "43/33/44"
  }
]
```

And the list should just ouput news1 and news2.
Does anyone know how to handle?
I also tried a filter. I tried to add a counting variable in there. But it's not in the right scope to read the count variable.
There must be an easy way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Greetz
Gilles

Answer (score 1):

I found a solutions which might help others too.
In my case im using a list. This list has a function named collectData and it's possible to overwrite it.
Here is how my function looks

```
"collectData" : function(records, index) {
  var recs = [];
  var start = (index > records.length) ? 0 : index;
  var limit = (start+this.limit > records.length) ? records.length : start+this.limit;
  for(var i=start; i < limit; i++) {recs[i] = records[i]['data'];}
  return recs;
}
```

I just needed to add a limit-attribute to my list which is on the same level as collectData.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a bit? I am facing the same problem. I am not sure on how to implement the paging for my list.